# how to manipulate two arrays by single foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays. Values of these arrays are posted via a form. What I want is to insert values of these arrays into the database. Here is my code.

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
    $subject=$_POST['subject'];
    $total=$_POST['total'];
    $attendee_array = $_POST['att'];
    $cnic_array=$_POST['cnic'];

    foreach(($attendee_array as $attendee) and ($cnic_array as $cnic)) {
        $query1=mysql_query("INSERT INTO course VALUES('','$subject','$total','$attendee','$cnic')") or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

It's not working. How can I do this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the key of the first array to access the item in the second. This works if you are trying to insert attendee 0 with cnic 0, attendee 1 with cnic 1 and so on.

```
foreach(($attendee_array as $key => $attendee)) {

    $cnic = mysql_real_escape_string($cnic_array[$key]);
    $attendee = mysql_real_escape_string($attendee);
    // do same as above for all user input ^^^

    $query1=mysql_query("INSERT INTO course VALUES('','$subject','$total','$attendee','$cnic')") or die(mysql_error());

}
```

I added escaping for SQL Injection, but you should look into a modern API with parameterised queries such as PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: I also use [strip_tags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to remove HTML and PHP code from the variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mi = new MultipleIterator();
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($attendee_array));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($cnic_array));

foreach ( $mi as $value ) {
    list($attendee,$cnic) = $value;
    ....etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about your original array keys, you can use `array_combine` to make one array be the keys and the other the values, and then call both key and value in your foreach loop:

```
$name = array('Chris','Steve','Dave');
$city = array('New York','San Diego','Dallas');

foreach(array_combine($name, $city) as $k => $v){
    echo $k.' lives in '.$v.'<br/>';    
}

Chris lives in New York
Steve lives in San Diego
Dave lives in Dallas
```

so in your example it would look like this:

```
foreach(array_combine($attendee_array,$cnic_array) as $attendee => $cnic) {
    $query1=mysql_query("INSERT INTO course VALUES('','$subject','$total','$attendee','$cnic')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```